# Using video module with ffmpeg to convert; how do I display converted files?

Tags: files

All uploaded videos on our Drupal 7 site need to be in a standard web format: MP4-H.264/AAC to assure play back by all user devices.

ffmpeg is working correctly. Video upload field stores all uploaded files into sites/default/files/videos/originals.

ffmpeg saves converted files into sites/default/files/videos/converted/nnnn which is a directory containing the converted file, and nnnn is a number unique for each file.

On the web page, the original uploaded file is displayed. How can I switch to the converted ("transcoded") file?

Video module supports Rules integration. Is that a good solution?

Production and QA sites are hosted on AWS.

Comment: Rules has 2 events for transcoding:  video_success, and video_failed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by modifying the custom module. Test if file has been converted, by looking in sites/default/files/videos/converted/nnnn, where nnnn is the File ID of the original file. If not then display the original video file. If conversion completed successfully, then display the converted file from sites/default/files/videos/converted/nnnn. There is only one file in the nnnn directory.